# What is the undo Zoom event called?

Tags: c#, data-visualization

Using Winforms Data.Visualization.Charting

I use the mouse to zoom in.

When I press the little "circle" at end of xAxis scroll bar the view reverts to previous.

What is this event called - I wish to do something when this happens.

Comment: What component are you using to draw your graphs?

Comment: Winforms Data.Visualization.Charting

Comment: any scrolling and zooming in or out will trigger the AxisViewChanged event. It is up to you to discern the actual event. When the reset button has been clicke all sizes in the ViewEventArgs are set to NaN and the type to Auto, afaik..

Comment: @Taw Actually that's not quite right. Pressing yAxis "unzoom" button does trigger the event. BUT Pressing xAxis "unzoom" does NOT

Comment: It certainly does here. I have no idea why it would not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the resetting of the axes zooms like this:

```
private void chart1_AxisViewChanged(object sender, ViewEventArgs e)
{

    if ( double.IsNaN(e.NewPosition)  &&  double.IsNaN(e.NewPosition))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Axis.AxisName + " axis reset.");
        // doYourThing
    }
}
```

Note that there is also the `AxisViewChanging` event. It is probably better suited for modifying the `IntervalType` to suit the new range of values..

Comment: For me the xAxis change is still NOT caught - what might have disabled that?

Comment: Beats me. Does it actually happen? So you can see changes?

Comment: I want to simulate what happens when I press the little circle at end of the scrollbar WITHOUT pressing it... SO that I can create a button that does both y and x axis at the same time. Therefore I need to know what to call?

Comment: Well, that is quit a different thing than what you asked (_What is this event called - I wish to do something when this happens._). Unfortunatlely I can't help you in calling it and even doubt that it can be done. I don't think it has any api to use; note that Chart is not an original Winforms control. It is a 3d party addition. I don't event know that the sources are out there.. But of course you can do all that is necessary wrt the AxisView's properties to get the same effect.